# SQL Server 2016 load cpu issue with prc_QueryNotifications, how to fix?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015, sql-server-2016

On WinSrv2012R2Standard installed MS SQL 2016. Also installed TFS 2015.
And it loads CPU on about 25%-75% all time.
When I connected with profiler and found that all time executed:

> exec sp_reset_connection
>
> exec prc_QueryNotifications @lastEventId=22424

It looks like:
[image]

So how to fix the SQL server for high CPU loads?

**UPDATE 1**

The result of execution of the sp_who2 below:

[image]

So as I see the resource monitor have abnormal cpu loading, how to fix it?

Comment: How you are confirming that SQL Server is causing high CPU in your server?

Comment: I see it in the Task Manager. Other processes loads less than 1% cpu, only SQL server loads at least 25% cpu

Comment: I doubt there queries are the root cause of the high CPU. What value does the CPU column show.  Perhaps there is a long-running query.  Check with Activity Monitor or sp_who2.

Comment: You don't mention, but you look to have TFS installed, probably worth re-tagging this, if it is - although I don't know of a problem with it's perf.

Comment: When did this performance issue occurs? This will help to judge whether it related to TFS? If without  TFS installed, did this issue also exist. You can also check TFS logs if there are some useful information.

Comment: I installed MSSQL and then TFS - reboot, create tfs projects - reboot  and server starts to work. During few hours I found that TFS works too slowly. I opened Task manager and found great cpu loads by MS SQL. I watched few days and see the same picture. Than I ask on the stackoverflow. Is it TFS guilty? I dont know - I dont use MS SQL without it. I look in the TFS logs and nothing strange see - but I don`t know what to search. I will be very appreciated for help with cpu loading.